# how to get request path with express req object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express + node.js and I have a req object, the request in the browser is /account but when I log req.path I get '/' --- not '/account'.

```
  //auth required or redirect
  app.use('/account', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.path);
    if ( !req.session.user ) {
      res.redirect('/login?ref='+req.path);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
```

req.path is / when it should be /account ??

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

Comment: req.route.path is correct and documented [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.route). Which version of express are you using?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. `req.route` is undefined. Im using express 3.4.4. What can cause route to be undefined?

Comment: @vinayr req.route.path still gives me /create instead of /quizzes/create, which is the whole URL

Comment: This is intended behavior. And you should embrace it. Your handler should not care about the full path, but only about the 'local' part of the path. That's the part after the path it was mounted on. This makes the handler function more easy to reuse in other contexts.

Comment: There's now a way to do this in later version.  See my answer below.

Comment: It's undefined inside middleware handlers only. Inside route handlers there's a route for sure.

Comment: As mentioned by @c1moore it's not possible to get complete path using req object. Although if you patch express then you can record this info in req. I ended up making this package [px5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/px5) to do it.

Comment: req.route will always be defined if you use app.all to mount the middleware, rather than app.use

Answer (score 337, accepted):

After having a bit of a play myself, you should use:

`console.log(req.originalUrl)`

Comment: I think its got something to do with the positioning of middleware, but you are correct, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's definitely the middleware.  This happens with additional routers in Express 4 as well.  When either is mounted off of a given path, inside of itself it gets to pretend that it's off of the root.  That's nice for isolation, but tricky when you don't know how to get what the original full value was.  Thanks for posting this!

Comment: Anyone getting here on 4.0, req.url is designed to be mutable by middleware for re-routing purposes, and req.path could be missing mounting points depending upon where it's called.
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl

Comment: If you don't want the query string included: `const path = req.originalUrl.replace(/\?.*$/, '');`

Comment: Warning: This is a misleading answer, based on the OP question. This will also return the query string (e.g. ?a=b&c=5) if it was present. See http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl

Comment: This simply does not give a path but a full url... Also useful but not what OP asked. To do what OP wants, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56380963/286685).

Comment: I don't think `req.originalUrl` is a good solution in this scenario. In Firebase Function, you'll get `/project-id/us-central1/app/account` instead of `/account`. You may also get an obsolete URL, which has been permanently redirected.

Answer (score 101):

Here is an example expanded from the documentation, which nicely wraps all you need to know about accessing the paths/URLs in all cases with express:

```
app.use('/admin', function (req, res, next) { // GET 'http://www.example.com/admin/new?a=b'
  console.dir(req.originalUrl) // '/admin/new?a=b' (WARNING: beware query string)
  console.dir(req.baseUrl) // '/admin'
  console.dir(req.path) // '/new'
  console.dir(req.baseUrl + req.path) // '/admin/new' (full path without query string)
  next()
})
```

Based on: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl

**Conclusion:** As [c1moore's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44788142/4465895) states, use:

```
var fullPath = req.baseUrl + req.path;
```

Answer (score 83):

In some cases you should use:

```
req.path
```

This gives you the path, instead of the complete requested URL. For example, if you are only interested in which page the user requested and not all kinds of parameters the url:

```
/myurl.htm?allkinds&ofparameters=true
```

req.path will give you:

```
/myurl.html
```

Comment: Be careful that if you're doing checks against this URL to also include a check for a trailing slash if it's valid in your app. (i.e. checking for `/demo` should also potentially check for `/demo/`).

Comment: If you don't want the query string included: const path = req.originalUrl.replace(/\?.*$/, '');

Comment: `req.path` is the shorthand of `url.parse(req.url).pathname` and this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @sertsedat Incorrect. `req.path` gives you the relative path to where your app is mounted. If it is mounted at the root than this is correct, but for a path `/my/path`, within an app mounted at `/my`, `req.url` will give `/path`.

Answer (score 19):

This can produce different results when **calling directly in base module** i.e. *main file (e.g. `index.js` or `app.js`)* vs **calling from inside module via `app.use()` middleware** i.e. *route file (e.g. `routes/users.js`)*.

###### API call:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/users/profile/123/summary?view=grid&leng=en
```

We'll be comparing our outputs against above API call

---

### First, we'll see the result from *innner module*:

1. We'll be placing our **user** module inside **routes** directory, with one route i.e. `/profile/:id/:details`

   **routes/users.js** file

   ```javascript
   const router = (require('express')).Router();

   router.get('/profile/:id/:details', (req, res) => {

       console.log(req.protocol);        // http or https
       console.log(req.hostname);        // only hostname without port
       console.log(req.headers.host);    // hostname with port number (if any); same result with req.header('host')
       console.log(req.route.path);      // exact defined route
       console.log(req.baseUrl);         // base path or group prefix
       console.log(req.path);            // relative path except query params
       console.log(req.url);             // relative path with query|search params
       console.log(req.originalUrl);     // baseURL + url

       // Full URL
       console.log(`${req.protocol}://${req.header('host')}${req.originalUrl}`);

       res.sendStatus(200);

   });

   module.exports = router;
   ```
2. Now we'll import this **user** module in main module of the application and add `/api/users` as base path for user module using `app.use()` middleware

   **index.js** file

   ```javascript
   const app = (require('express'))();

   const users = require('./routes/users');
   app.use('/api/users', users);

   const server = require('http').createServer(app);
   server.listen(8000, () => console.log('server listening'));
   ```

##### Output

> [req.protocol] ............. `http`
> [req.hostname] .......... `localhost`
> [req.headers.host] ..... `localhost:8000`
> [req.route.path] .......... `/profile/:id/:details`
> [req.baseUrl] .............. `/api/users`
> [req.path] ................... `/profile/123/summary`
> [req.url] ...................... `/profile/123/summary?view=grid&leng=en`
> [req.originalUrl] .......... `/api/users/profile/123/summary?view=grid&leng=en`

> Full URL:
> `http://localhost:8000/api/users/profile/123/summary?view=grid&leng=en`

---

### Now, we'll see result if we add routes directly in *main module*:

1. We'll define our route right in the *main module* (i.e. app.js or index.js) and concatenate base path `/app/users` with route path instead of using middleware. So route will become `/api/users/profile/:id/:details`

   **index.js** file

   ```javascript
   const app = (require('express'))();

   app.get('/api/users/profile/:id/:details', (req, res) => {

       console.log(req.protocol);        // http or https
       console.log(req.hostname);        // only hostname without port
       console.log(req.headers.host);    // hostname with port number (if any); same result with req.header('host')
       console.log(req.route.path);      // exact defined route
       console.log(req.baseUrl);         // base path or group prefix
       console.log(req.path);            // relative path except query params
       console.log(req.url);             // relative path with query|search params
       console.log(req.originalUrl);     // baseURL + url

       // Full URL
       console.log(`${req.protocol}://${req.header('host')}${req.originalUrl}`);

       res.sendStatus(200);

   });

   const server = require('http').createServer(app);
   server.listen(8000, () => console.log('server listening'));
   ```

##### Output

> [req.protocol] ............. `http`
> [req.hostname] .......... `localhost`
> [req.headers.host] ..... `localhost:8000`
> [req.route.path] .......... `/api/users/profile/:id/:details`
> [req.baseUrl] ..............  
> [req.path] ................... `/api/users/profile/123/summary`
> [req.url] ...................... `/api/users/profile/123/summary?view=grid&leng=en`
> [req.originalUrl] .......... `/api/users/profile/123/summary?view=grid&leng=en`

> Full URL:
> `http://localhost:8000/api/users/profile/123/summary?view=grid&leng=en`

We can clearly see in above output that the only difference is of `baseUrl` which is empty string here. So, the `originalUrl` also changes & looks same as the `url`

Comment: `req.route` is `undefined`

Comment: can you share your code snippet (e.g. JSFiddle etc)?

Comment: The example code is correct, but the results in the answer are not. In the second example, `/api/users` doesn't appear in the posted output at all, which doesn't even make sense in that context.

Comment: In second example's output, I haven't listed `/api/users` at all. See the value against `[baseUrl]` is empty

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATE 8 YEARS LATER:**

`req.path` was [already doing exactly same thing](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/b400814d000613745673e39a6e1cd294a69a2677/lib/request.js#L416) that I mentioned here. I don't remember how this answer solved issue and accepted as a correct answer but currently **it's not a valid answer**. Please ignore this answer. Thanks @mhodges for mentioning this.

**Original answer:**

If you want to really get only "path" without querystring, you can use `url` library to parse and get only path part of url.

```
var url = require('url');

//auth required or redirect
app.use('/account', function(req, res, next) {
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    if ( !req.session.user ) {
      res.redirect('/login?ref='+path);
    } else {
      next();
    }
});
```

Comment: this exactly is what i want. Use it with ```req.query.ref``` if login successful

Comment: This works nicely with universal code since it conforms to [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) spec.  Less things to remember and easier to unit test across client and server.

Comment: `req.path` is just an alias for `url.parse(req.url).pathname`

Comment: @mhodges Wow, that looks completely true. This is a 8 years old answer and I have no clue how we thought that answer solves the issue. Thanks for mentioning. I'll update answer or maybe just delete it.

Answer (score 13):

```
//auth required or redirect
app.use('/account', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.path);
  if ( !req.session.user ) {
    res.redirect('/login?ref='+req.path);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

> req.path is / when it should be /account ??

The reason for this is that Express subtracts the path your handler function is mounted on, which is `'/account'` in this case.

Why do they do this?

Because it makes it easier to reuse the handler function. You can make a handler function that does different things for `req.path === '/'` and `req.path === '/goodbye'` for example:

```
function sendGreeting(req, res, next) {
  res.send(req.path == '/goodbye' ? 'Farewell!' : 'Hello there!')
}
```

Then you can mount it to multiple endpoints:

```
app.use('/world', sendGreeting)
app.use('/aliens', sendGreeting)
```

Giving:

```
/world           ==>  Hello there!
/world/goodbye   ==>  Farewell!
/aliens          ==>  Hello there!
/aliens/goodbye  ==>  Farewell!
```

Comment: I'm amazed this answer isn't voted up much more, since it clearly answers the question and explains the behaviour (unlike all the higher-voted answers). Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

It should be:

`req.url`

express 3.1.x

Comment: req.url is not a native Express property, it is inherited from Node’s http module: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl

Answer (score 11):

For version 4.x you can now use the `req.baseUrl` in addition to `req.path` to get the full path.  For example, the OP would now do something like:

```
//auth required or redirect
app.use('/account', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.baseUrl + req.path);  // => /account

  if(!req.session.user) {
    res.redirect('/login?ref=' + encodeURIComponent(req.baseUrl + req.path));  // => /login?ref=%2Faccount
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

> req.route.path is working for me

```
var pool = require('../db');

module.exports.get_plants = function(req, res) {
    // to run a query we can acquire a client from the pool,
    // run a query on the client, and then return the client to the pool
    pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM plants', function(err, result) {
            //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
            done();
            if (err) {
                return console.error('error running query', err);
            }
            console.log('A call to route: %s', req.route.path + '\nRequest type: ' + req.method.toLowerCase());
            res.json(result);
        });
    });
};
```

after executing I see the following in the console and I get perfect result
in my browser.

```
Express server listening on port 3000 in development mode
A call to route: /plants
Request type: get
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a middleware in express, your request object has several properties you can use to get the correct path:

- req.baseUrl: `/api/account`
- req.originalUrl: `/api/account`
- req._parsedUrl.path: `/account`
- req._parsedUrl.pathname: `/account`
- req._parsedUrl.href: `/account`
- req._parsedUrl._raw: `/account`

PLEASE NOTE: This applies to middlewares

Answer (score 0):

For those getting `undefined` from `req.route.path` that is correct.

Inside route handler, there's a route.
Inside middleware handlers, there's no route.