# Redirect paths to base "/" paths with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

With Express, how can I redirect all urls with "/something" to the base path "/:=" including additional paths to their respective pages. For example, I want to redirect the following:

1. "/something" to "/"
2. "/something/else" to "/else"
3. "/something/else/again" to "/else/again"
4. etc...

How can I achieve that with Express?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/something/*', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 4):

`req.originalUrl` will give you original path and from that you need to remove the `something` part. Can you try:

```
router.get('/something/*', function(req, res) {
  var newPath = req.originalUrl.split('something')[1]
  res.redirect(newPath);
});
```

You can also use `req.path`, but there are some [scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525928/how-to-get-request-path-with-express-req-object) it might not work.

Comment: req.path is useful too in this case