# How to get the exact URL path defined by me in express middleware without path parameter values and query parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url, express-router

I have a requirement to get the exact path of the URL for use in another middleware for resusability purposes. It should return the url without the path parameter converted to specific value, and without the query parameter.

Eg: if the user enters `https://localhost:3000/path1/4/path2`, where `/4` is defined as `/:id` in my defined path, then the extracted path should be `/path1/:id/path2`.

So far, the only useful ways I have found are:

1. using `req.originalUrl` => would return `/path1/4/path2`
2. using `req.baseUrl + req.path` => would return `/path/4/path2` as well, same as above
3. using `req.route.path` => would actually return the required output `/path1/:id/path2`, but unfortunately does not work when **nesting routes with express router** as it only returns the nested path.

For example and reference, please have a look at the below snippet:

```
const express = require("express");

const routes = express.Router();
routes.get("/path2", async (req, res, next) => {

    //assuming a URL of "https://localhost:3000/path1/12/path2?someparam=5"
    //desired output: "/path1/:id/path2"

    console.log(req.originalUrl) // returns "/path1/12/path2"
    console.log(req.baseUrl + req.path); // returns "/path1/12/path2"
    console.log(req.route.path); //returns only "/path2"

});

app.use("/path1/:id", routes); //using the router to nest paths makes req.route.path unusable
```

I have referred to the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525928/how-to-get-request-path-with-express-req-object), but they don't suit my exact requirements. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Anyone trying to get the path, It's not possible directly but express can be patched to add that to req object. I ended up making this package [px5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/px5) to do it.