# How to get appended URL value? (e.g. localhost:3000/URL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

I'm trying to use other URL to be used as a data in my app.

For example, If I visit `localhost:3000/https://www.google.com/robots.txt`

Then I would like to get `https://www.google.com/robots.txt` as a parameter so I can use it.

I tried the following approach but it only works if the trailing value has no slash.

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.params)
})
```

Is there a possible way to get the appended URL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get request path with express req object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525928/how-to-get-request-path-with-express-req-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/*` to grab the Parameters and then get the index `0` to get the exact URL

```js
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  var url = req.params[0];
  res.send(url);
});
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly! Do you know if it's possible to send index.html with that parameter?

Comment: You can follow this guide to do that : https://codeforgeek.com/render-html-file-expressjs/