# document.location.href.split('/'); in express

Tags: node.js, express, glitch-framework

How would I do this in express: `document.location.href.split('/');` I have already tried using the res function too. I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525928/how-to-get-request-path-with-express-req-object

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to do. And, what error did you get?